# Swift raw pointer to 2D Array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, unsafemutablepointer

I have a pointer (buffer.contents() in code below) of type UnsafeMutableRawPointer which is a buffer of length N and holds 16 bit unsigned integers. I want to view this as a 2D array of size K x L (where K*L = N) of 16 bit unsigned integers. How do I convert this to a 2D array so that I can either print it as 2D array or better, see the contents in debugger window? This is what I did and using this pointer I can iterate over members one by one, but I cannot visualize the entire array in one shot.

```
let pointer = unsafeBitCast(buffer.contents(), to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.self)
```

Comment: K * L = N but only N is known or did I miss something? How do you get the dimensions of your array?

Comment: K & L are fixed, all K,L,N are known. Assume them to be constants.